# DiagnosticOrder.Item - How should I incorporate other attributes

Tags: dstu2-fhir, hl7-fhir

In our system , DiagnosticOrder.Item has many attributes. Example,
1. Code
2. Name
3. Parent Code
4. Problem with the code
5. Automatically added code ... and many more.

Seems to me , it will be more appropriate to create a new resource here. I see  that DiagnosticOrder.Item is a backbone element.

Question is , should I create a new resource or should I use extension here for DiagnosticOrder.Item?

I am more inclined to create a new resource - but not sure how to create one ? If I have to create one , can you please guide me to create a new resource ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, creating your own resource is non-compliant, though you could profile the Basic resource.  What you're looking for sounds like an extension to me, though you could also look at DataElement.